# Mouse move to wake from sleep only opens one of two displays

Tags: 22.04, multiple-monitors, suspend, mouse, power-management

On Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS I have two displays plugged into a Dell Inc. OptiPlex 9020.  An HP 22ER display, the one which always comes up, is plugged into an HDMI port, the other LG display is connected to a Display Port socket using a Display Port to HDMI cable.  When I wake the system from sleep by wiggling the USB wired mouse only the HP display plugged into the HDMI port is activated, and this is *not* the one with the top menu including the "power button" icon.  I have to remember to always wake the system up using the keyboard.  After the failed mouse-initiated wakeup I have to sit back and wait for the system to go back to sleep, and then hit a key on the keyboard to continue.  How can I correct this behaviour?  FYI I have included the monitors.xml file.

By the way it strikes me as *unethical* to have a configuration file whose interpretation is apparently not documented except apparently by users prepared to read the source code of the module that processes it.

https://wiki.gnome.org/Attic/RandR

```
<monitors version="2">
  <configuration>
    <logicalmonitor>
      <x>1920</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <scale>1</scale>
      <monitor>
        <monitorspec>
          <connector>HDMI-2</connector>
          <vendor>HWP</vendor>
          <product>HP 22er</product>
          <serial>3CM7430GNZ   </serial>
        </monitorspec>
        <mode>
          <width>1920</width>
          <height>1080</height>
          <rate>60</rate>
        </mode>
      </monitor>
    </logicalmonitor>
    <logicalmonitor>
      <x>0</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <scale>1</scale>
      <primary>yes</primary>
      <monitor>
        <monitorspec>
          <connector>VGA-1</connector>
          <vendor>GSM</vendor>
          <product>LG IPS FULLHD</product>
          <serial>502NDFV1F227</serial>
        </monitorspec>
        <mode>
          <width>1920</width>
          <height>1080</height>
          <rate>60</rate>
        </mode>
      </monitor>
    </logicalmonitor>
  </configuration>
</monitors>
```

Comment: x.org or wayland?

Comment: Actually I first encountered this on X but the same thing happens on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS running Wayland.